# How do I move a file after fclose() using C

Tags: c, file, fclose

I'm trying to move some .csv files from a directory "NotImported" to another directory "Imported" after each file fclose().

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way!

Comment: *ain't found anything* - what did you look for?

Comment: Notice that the notion of directory is not in standard C99 or C11.

Answer (score 2):

I would say,

```
rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);
```

all explained here (it's long to read but you'll learn a lot each time): [man page of rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html)

Comment: This is correct, but won't work (on Linux) when `NotImported` and  `Imported` are on a different file system (a very unlikely situation). In such rare case, OP needs to copy byte by byte the file, and finally remove the oldpath